# How to detect user sign out in sharepoint Provider Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom, session

I want to detect when user logout from SharePoint site to SharePoint add-in.
Now I'm getting current user using this code:

```
var user = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
clientContext.Load(user);
await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

My problem is, if I logout from SharePoint site after try to get current user from my add-in page request, then it's returning previous user's data.

How to validate if the user is active or not?

I created this SharePoint add-in using asp.net MVC.

If I simply say this,if I signout from sharepoint site,then I can get the current user details from already opened sharepoint add-in web page request using csom.I want to avoid that

Comment: try your code, after clearing the cookies ?

Comment: In this case,I only sign out from sharepoint site, not in the add-in.So how to detect user signout from the sharepoint site to add-in page

Comment: If I simply say this,if I signout from sharepoint site,then I can get the current user details using csom.I want to avoid that

Comment: having the same issue